# deploy node api to vercel

Tags: node.js, deployment, vercel

I'm trying to deploy a node express backend on Vercel, but I'm always getting 404 or 500.

I have a folder on the root of the project named "handlers", inside of it, there're multiple folders with the routes and um index.js file that gets all promises and send to the index.js file on the root of the project.

I'm not so sure how the vercel.config should be.

[handler/index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdyrR.png)
[folders structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrODb.png)

[handler/*.js example]

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");
const { promisify } = require("util");
/**
 * @param {*} event
 * @param {*} models
 * @returns
 */

module.exports.handler = async function (event, models) {

    const execPromise = promisify(exec);

    const pythonReturn = await execPromise("python3 app.py");
  
    const result = JSON.parse(pythonReturn.stdout)
  
      return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(result),
      };
  
  };
  
  module.exports.path = "/getSurebets";
  module.exports.method = "GET";
```

---

[server.js]

```
'use strict'

const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express()
const router = express.Router()
const aliveTime = new Date().getTime()
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3002; 
const Handler = require("./index")

router.use(cors())
router.use(bodyParser.json())
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  req.json({ aliveTime })
})

router.use(async function(req, res){
  const event = {
    "resource": req.path,
    "path": req.path,
    "httpMethod": req.method,
    "headers": req.headers,
    "queryStringParameters": req.query,
    "pathParameters": req.params,
    "stageVariables": null,
    "body": JSON.stringify(req.body),
    "isBase64Encoded": false,
    "requestContext": {
      "authorizer": {}
    }
  }

  try{
    const response = await Handler.handler(event)
    res
      .set(response.headers)
      .status(response.statusCode)
    
    const data = response.body
      
    if(req.path.indexOf("render") < 0){
      res.send(JSON.parse(data))
    }else{
      res.send(data)
    }

  }catch(e){
    console.error(e)
    res.status(500).send(e)
  }
})

app.use('/v1/', router)
app.listen(PORT)

console.log(`Listen on http://0.0.0.0:${PORT}`)
module.exports = app
```

---

root/index.js

```
const fns = require("./handlers")
const cors = require('./lib/cors')
const models = require("./models");


const extractPathValues = (pathExpression, httpPath) => {
  const pathExpressionPattern = pathExpression.replace(/{[\w]+}|:[\w]+/g, '([^/]+)')
  const pathValueRegex = new RegExp(`^${pathExpressionPattern}$`)
  const pathValues = pathValueRegex.exec(httpPath)
  return pathValues && pathValues.length > 0 ? pathValues.slice(1) : null
}

const extractPathNames = (pathExpression) => {
  const pathExpressionPattern = pathExpression?.replace(/{[\w.]+}|:[\w.]+/g, '[:{]([\\w]+)}?');
  const pathNameRegex = new RegExp(`^${pathExpressionPattern}$`)
  const pathNames = pathNameRegex.exec(pathExpression)
  return pathNames && pathNames.length > 0 ? pathNames.slice(1) : null
}

const getRouterHandler = (event) => {
  const routesByMethod = fns.filter(r => r.method === event.httpMethod)
  for(const route of routesByMethod) {
    const pathPartNames = extractPathNames(route.path)
    const pathValues = extractPathValues(route.path, event.path)
    if (pathValues && pathPartNames) {
      const params = {}
      let keyIndex = 0;
      for(const key of pathPartNames) {
        params[ key ] = pathValues[ keyIndex ]
        keyIndex++;
      }
      return {route, params}
    }
  }
}

const getHandler = async (event) => {
  return getRouterHandler(event)
}

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  if(event.Records) return tRender(event, context, models)
  if(process.env.NODE_ENV!=='test') console.log(event)
  const HANDLER = await getHandler(event)
  if(!HANDLER) return { statusCode: 404, body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'Not Found' }) }
  const { route, params } = HANDLER
  if(!event.pathParameters || !Object.keys(event.pathParameters).length) {
    event.pathParameters = params
  }
  
  if((process.env.NODE_ENV || '').trim() !== 'test') console.debug({ event }) 

  const response = cors(
    await route.handler(event, models, context).catch(err => {
      console.error(err)
      if(!err.statusCode || !err.body ) {
        return Promise.reject(err)
      }
      return Promise.resolve(err)
    })
  )
  return response
}
```

---

[vercel.config]

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "name": "omnes-api",
    "builds": [
       { "src": "index.js", "use": "@vercel/node" }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
          "src": "handlers/index.js",
          "dest": "index.js"
        }
      ]
 }
```

Error:

[image]